# Beginner struggling with a simple drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html

Specifically, I'm trying to make a drop down menu filled with links that will direct to the specified locations in google maps when clicked. I managed to get google maps embedded into my page, but for some reason I cannot seem to get the drop down to occur and cannot find the problem in my code. I also am struggling to understand how to actually create the links in the dropdown menu to direct to the selected location on the google map. Any help would be appreciated. The code I have so far...

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show')
      }
    }
  }
}

function initMap() {
  var Columbia = {
    lat: 34.006140,
    lng: -81.037532
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: Columbia
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: Columbia,
    map: map
  });
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

#map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB5cD8oVYji2MWCAj8JzrAzQtpBy12W30o&callback=initMap">
</script>
<h3>Google Maps/Form Assignment</h3>
<div id="map"></div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Select a location</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#london">London, England</a>
    <a href="#tokyo">Tokyo, Japan</a>
    <a href="#newyork">New York City, USA</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1) the class `dropdown-content` has display of none but there is no style defined for class `show` so display sticks to none, and 2) you have a syntax error on `document.getElementByClassName`, replace it with `document.getElementsByClassName`

Comment: i will post an answer with your solution, give me a moment

Answer (score 0):

I see you have added 2 different functions for the same process, you only need 1 so i will show the code with the fixes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        .dropbtn {
            background-color: #4caf50;
            color: white;
            padding: 16px;
            font-size: 16px;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus{
            background-color: #3e8e41;
        }
        .dropdown{
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .dropdown-content{
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            min-width: 160px;
            overflow: auto;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            z-index: 1;
        }
        /*Add this rule so the dropdown can be shown*/
        .dropdown-content.show{
            display: block;
        }
        .dropdown-content a {
            color: black;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
        }
        .dropdown a:hover {
            background-color: #f1f1f1
        }
        #map {
            height: 400px;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Google Maps/Form Assignment</h3>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Select a location</button>
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#london">London, England</a>
            <a href="#tokyo">Tokyo, Japan</a>
            <a href="#newyork">New York City, USA</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        window.onclick = function(event){
            var target = event.target;

            if(target.matches('.dropbtn')){
                var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content"); //This returns a HTMLCollection

                for(i=0; i < dropdowns.length; i++){
                    // Since dropdowns is a HTMLCollection, extract the node from the collection
                    var dropdown = dropdowns.item(i);

                    // Toggle the dropdown whenever the button is clicked
                    dropdown.classList.toggle("show");
                }
            }

            if(target.matches(".dropdown-content > a")){
                // Get the location name from the hash
                var location = target.hash.slice(1);

                // Extract the location map and set it as center
                map.setCenter(positions[location]);
            }
        };
        </script>
        <script>
            function initMap() {
                // Set all locations map
                window.positions = {
                    london: {
                        lat: 51.5013616,
                        lng: -0.1965444
                    },
                    southCarolina: {
                        lat: 34.006140,
                        lng: -81.037532
                    } 
                };

                window.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom: 4,
                    center: positions.southCarolina
                });

                // Add marker positions in the map
                var markers = {
                    london: new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: positions.london,
                        map: map
                    }),
                    southCarolina: new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: positions.southCarolina,
                        map: map
                    })
                };
            }

    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB5cD8oVYji2MWCAj8JzrAzQtpBy12W30o&callback=initMap">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

i have added in the comments what should have been done as difference from your code.

You need to know that `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTMLCollection` object which only has `length` as property and 2 methods which are `item` and `namedItem`, you can see the docs for [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) and docs for [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/getElementsByClassName)

**EDIT:** I have also added a section code for handling the map position view when a dropdown item is clicked, note i just added an example for `london` so you could continue doing the rest for other locations